# Examine $dirty and $invalid for Dynamic Field Names in Angular JS version 1.1.5

Tags: angularjs, validation, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have dynamic field names such as below: Here field names are coming from the controller and are generated dynamically. I am trying to do  validations and I want to print $dirty and $invalid flag for them.

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
<ng-form name="myForm">
**dirty: {{myForm.fruitId_[fruit.fruitname].$dirty}}
invalid: {{myForm.fruitId_[fruit.fruitname].$invalid}}**
```

This field is required
                    Please enter at the most 8 characters

Here the below two statements :

```
**dirty: {{myForm.fruitId_[fruit.fruitname].$dirty}}
invalid: {{myForm.fruitId_[fruit.fruitname].$invalid}}**
```

Don't display anything. I appreciate your inputs.

Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ehe3mNknCXV5PzDrxl8z?p=preview

**FIX:** 
I figured that angular needs {{}} for the field name in version1.1.5 and these brackets need to be escaped too.

```
<ng-form name="myForm"> 
      <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">

       dirty: {{myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$dirty}}
       invalid: {{myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$invalid}} 
       {{fruit.fruitname}} Textbox: <input type="text" name="{{fruit.fruitname}}" auto-id="fruitId_{{color}}_{{fruit.fruitname}}" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="8" ng-model="data[fruit.fruitname]"  />
                <div class="validation-message" ng-show="myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$dirty && myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$error.required">This field is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="myForm['\{\{fruit.fruitname\}\}'].$error.maxlength">Please enter at the most 8 characters</span>
                </div>

       </div>

  </ng-form>
```

I updated the plunker with working version - http://plnkr.co/edit/SmwXXI38mgED7UJNtjuE?p=preview.

Comment: set up a plunker please?

Comment: I can see right away that your form tag is repeating for every ng-repeat condition. Is that what you want? FYI... That's not going to work.

Comment: @Aakash : I moved it outside the ng-repeat as you suggested. Still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the posted code:

1. You're using an obsolete version of angular. Use the last stable one, which does support dynamic fields
2. You have one form per field, always with the same name, instead of a global form
3. you repeat the name "myForm" in the name of the fields themselves. This is unnecessary and confusing
4. the name used in your expression is invalid.

Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qNzi1NT7Gv58kRF5Jp3V?p=preview):

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
   dirty: {{myForm['fruitId_' + fruit.fruitname].$dirty}}
   invalid: {{myForm['fruitId_' + fruit.fruitname].$invalid}}  
   {{fruit.fruitname}} Textbox: <input type="text" name="fruitId_{{fruit.fruitname}}" ng-required="true" ng-model="data[fruit.fruitname]" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It does not work. I just replaced in the plunker to test. I need to display the value of $dirty and $invalid. Also for the 1st point - I am tied to the older version of Angular atleast for now. for 2nd point - I agree. I updated the plunker and moved ng-form tag outside. for 3rd point - I believe this is necessary for printing the validation messages. If plunker proves that I am wrong. I will remove it

Comment: I forgot to provide a link to the plunkr. You'll see that it DOES work. If you're stuck with a buggy, officially unstable, version of angular from **2 years ago**, then the first thing you should do is upgrading.

Comment: So, are you saying that 1.1.5 version of Angular does not support dynamic fields ? I cant mark your response as answer ONLY because it does not work in 1.1.5. which is the version of angular I am using. I understand its not a good practice to use older version but for now I am stuck with this version.

Comment: 1.1 is an unstable, development branch of angular. You shouldn't be using any version from this branch. And yes, I'm pretty sure this oooold version didn't properly support dynamic fields. So, you could fork angular and fix it yourself, or you could upgrade to a stable, up-to-date version. If you expect a StackOverflow answer to provide a bug-fix for angular because you don't want to migrate, that won't happen.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a workaround. Updated the plunker.